# Laravel javascript and css imports

Tags: javascript, laravel, include

I download template and i put it into my laravel project and it works fine. 
I make my master layout filed and ith works on index route or on route with one slash example: localhot:8080/kategorija .

But when i visit route with wildcard (localhot:8080/kategorija/1/edit or localhot:8080/kategorija/create ) my imports ( css, javascript ) does not work.
i resolve problem with css adding asset code:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/AdminLTE.css') }}">
```

but still i cant resolve problem with javascripts

My head code with imports

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ isset($naslov) ? $naslov : 'Administracija' }}</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>


    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/AdminLTE.css') }}">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>


      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: The only javascript includes I can see are conditional. Are you testing it in IE version lower than 9? Or what exactly is not working?

Comment: i make mistake it is problem with my css maxcdn and cdnjs lines make problem

Comment: I don't see what the problem could be with those files. You are connected to the internet aren't you?

Comment: Apache mod rewrite loaded and working ? does the css files have correct permissions to be seen by the browser ?